# I need help deciphering a message

Tags: cipher

My ex-boyfriend sent me a message with these letters and said that 'he's finally brave enough to tell me', or some bullcrap like that. He said he wouldn't tell me the encryption type, but he'd tell me that the key is 'acdc23b'. I don't know about any of this stuff. Please help.

Message --> I nrxj epu Lhux O kuuw yfy oexht gxbvg hptahh vr ettgeuv

Comment: I suspect that the first four words decipher to "I love you Jess", but I can't reverse-engineer a cipher for that that matches the key.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> If you treat this as a Vigenere cipher (https://cryptii.com/vigenere-cipher, change to **DECODE**) and use the key 'acdcfgb' (Thanks @IanMacDonald, I had it backwards), you get:
>
> i love you jess i just was never brave enough to confess

Thanks to @F1Krazy for nailing the starting words

Comment: Key could also be `acdcfgb`, which is closer to what the person originally suggested (`acdc23b`).

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oops, I actually had it on ENCODE when I got that key.  Yes, that would actually be the key.  I updated my post to reflect that.  Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the 'fg' from 23, if I may ask?

Comment: @Jess You can just try different letters at that point.  The Vigenere cipher is pretty commonly used, so I started with that.  The problem is that it must be only letters, no numbers.  If you assume the key is still 7 letters long, and use acdcXYb, you can just start playing with the X and Y to make it work.  In this case, you'd see "I lov...", so just change the X around using that tool to make it an 'E'.  I'm not sure why exactly fg=23, except that I'd also assume ABCDEFGH=ABCD1234.  That's a bunch of assumptions, but I think it's mostly logical?